# Vaadin 10 scrollIntoView

Tags: vaadin, js-scrollintoview

My problem is with vaadin 10. In vaadin 8 we can use the `scrollIntoView` function but in vaadin 10 we can do it only by executing Javascript and we can scroll only in Grid type.

How to make it for other components like vertical layout in vaadin 10? (I need to scroll to vertical layout component)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer of my question..

Just write this code:
Page.getCurrent().getJavaScript().execute("document.getElementById(\"idOfElement\").scrollIntoView()")

Don't forget to set id to your component.
Found it here: https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/11503073

Answer (score 1):

In Vaadin [forum](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17467755) someone asked the same and there was another possible answer:

```
component.getElement().callJsFunction("scrollIntoView");
```

Tested in my application with Vaadin 14.6.x and worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think there no Java API yet for this, but it is possible to workaround it by following JavaScript call:

```
UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJavaScript("$0.scrollTo(0,$0.scrollHeight);", component);
```

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't help. When i write: UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJavaScript("$0.scrollTo(0,$0.scrollHeight);", myVL.getComponentAt(25));  it doesn't scroll and also doesn't give errors. Please, help with this problem.

Comment: UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({behavior:'smooth'});", *layoutname*)); should work here